# Javascript -- Closures with Simple Adder Function

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I'm a Python coder learning more about Javascript.

I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding Closures for some reason. I've produced the simple Adder function (i.e. Should do something like Add(1) = 1, Add(2) = 3...)

I've been trying to understand what's going on under the hood via console.log/printing everything but I'm confused on how these functions are different, if they are:

```
var makeAdder = function(num){
  var addNum=num;
  var letsAdd = function(num){
    return addNum+=num;
  };
  return letsAdd;
};

var makeAdder = function(numa){
  var letsAdd = function(numb){
    return numa+numb;
  };
  return letsAdd;
};

var a = makeAdder(2);
console.log(a(5));
// should produce 7 at the end
```

Comment: `var makeAdder` is defined twice... Why ? Works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rgz0vjxs/)

Comment: See: [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

Comment: @ArunPJohny please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/c605adxt/2/ they are a little different

Comment: @gurvinder372 missed the `=` in `+=`

Comment: Do you understand how global variables work?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for a simple adder function without using closures.

```
function makeAdder(num){
  if(!this.addNum){
    this.addNum=0;
  }
  return this.addNum+=num;
}

console.log("------------makeAdder----------");

console.log(makeAdder(10)); // output - 10
console.log(makeAdder(20)); // output - 30
console.log(makeAdder(30)); // output - 60
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit simpler and more concise:

```
function makeAdder(n) { 
    return function(x) {
        return x + n;   // closure over n
    };
};

var add5 = makeAdder(5);    
var add7 = makeAdder(7);    

console.log(add5(10));   // 15
console.log(add7(10));   // 17
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** `makeAdder` adds to last added value `addNum+=num;` which is why you can keep adding to the previously added value

So, first `makeAdder` will return what you want

```
var a = makeAdder(2);
a(1);//output 3
a(4);//output 7
```

However, **second** `makeAdder` is not adding to last added value `numa+numb;` so it is not able to add it to previous value

```
var a = makeAdder(2);
a(1);//output 3
a(4);//output 6 not 7
```

Comment: @RayonDabre try adding another value to a by doing `a(3);` again. In first method, it will add to previously added value, in second one (as in your fiddle), it will added to the original constructor value https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/c605adxt/1/

Comment: @RayonDabre and see the difference with first `makeAdder` https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/c605adxt/2/

Comment: @Guru, Difference seems to be like `a = a+2` and `a+2`

Comment: @RayonDabre yes precisely.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript when a variable is declared inside a function, it becomes local to that function. So when the function completes the execution, Garbage collector destroys all the local variables.
But in case of closures, it cannot. Because a link to those function variables gets created from outside the function.[image]

In the above picture N moves out of the scope of F and becomes available outside.
**A good read on closure is in Object Oriented Javascript by Stoyan Stefanov**

So in closures the local variables are not destroyed and the value is stored for future use.In your case, you are creating a closure by using the local variables **addnum** and **numa** in function **letsAdd** which is then returned outside the function and hence available from outside,creating a link.

The first makeadder has the local variable which has the sum of last two values i.e. **addnum** is saved. And hence when the next time you are calling, you are getting the sum.
While the second function has an external link to **numa** which is not the sum of last two variable. So the value gets saved is only the value of first parameter.
So in the subsequent calls the first parameter to the add is different in both the functions.